# Prevent multiple ajax requests onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, q

I've an issue with multiple ajax requests. For example I've a form with a button, and `onclick` it runs a service which essentially load list of items in a table; for now it should load a single item into a table when I hit the button.

However, when I hit the button multiple times, the same item is duplicated when its loaded.

How can I prevent while there is still no callback from the first one?

### current ng service

```
var getItems = function () {

    var def = $q.defer();

    Items.get().then(function (items) {
       def.resolve(items);
    }, function (err) {
       ...
    });
};
```

Not sure if this is a solution, but when I write above code like this:

```
var def = false;
var getItems = function () {

    def = $q.defer();

    Items.get().then(function (items) {
       def.resolve(items);
    }, function (err) {
       ...
    });
};
```

This stops the duplication when I initialize the `def = false`, not sure if this is the correct approach by resetting the previous/old request to `false`?

Comment: This seems like more of a logic issue than duplicated ajax requests... How does sending this request multiple times result in the same item being inserted into the collection multiple times? shouldn't the collection simply be set to the result, making it impossible to contain duplicates? Why are you appending the result to the collection?

Comment: Don't know, you didn't provide that code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a lock on the function to prevent the code from running multiple times at once or at all:

```
// your service
$scope.isRunning = false;

var getItems = function () {

    if(!$scope.isRunning){
        $scope.isRunning = true;
        var def = $q.defer();

        Items.get().then(function (items) {
           def.resolve(items);
        }, function (err) {
           ...
        }).finally(function(){
             //$scope.isRunning = false; // once done, reset isRunning to allow to run again. If you want it to run just once then exclude this line
        });
    }
};
```

Unsure how you want to handle the button in terms of being clicked multiple times

You can hide it on click:

```
<button ng-hide="isRunning">Stuff</button>
```

You can disable it on click:

```
<button ng-disabled="isRunning">Stuff</button>
```

if disabling, you should probably give feedback like changing opacity:

```
<button ng-disabled="isRunning" ng-class='{"opacity-half": isRunning}'>Stuff</button>
.opacity-half { opacity: 0.5 }
```

Comment: this is not the solution for question. this makes sync calls instead of async OP asked for cancelling the previous one not waiting for the result.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL, this DOES not make sync calls, angular does not allow sync calls. This just limits the function to on call until it is finishes; similar but not sync.

Comment: I did not mean sync for the request (as in AJAX) I meant the result  syncing of the async requests...

Comment: @Simple-Solution, the question is what do you want the function to do when it is clicked multiple times? If you want it to run just once, make the logic do that. If you want it to be limited to wait for a response before you make the next call, do that.

Comment: @Simple-Solution then this should work but also you can just make button disable or keep a variable in the controller to avoid requests.

Comment: I would suggest disabling the button, keeps the logic clean of flags and accidentally setting/unsetting them can happen. Disable the button when the first call goes out. Enable the button when you get a response from server.

Comment: One thing I learned is, if using AngularJS, do as prefered by AngularJS. Saves you from future hassles.  Refer to the ngDisbaled documentation for that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 2):

the below code should do the trick I am avoiding some angular specific syntax hope that helps;

```
function yourContoller(/*all injectables*/) {
  var requesting = false;
  $scope.buttonClick = function() {
     if (!requesting) {
       requesting = true;
       yourService.getItems().then(function(response) {
          /*your code to handle response*/
          requesting = false;
       });
     }
  };
}
```

if you want to disable a button in the view you can expose this variable by simply using scope (`$scope.requesting = false;`) with `ng-disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a reusable directive so that on any button which is clickable, it doesnt get pressed twice

```
app.directive('clickAndDisable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      clickAndDisable: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('click', function() {
        iElement.prop('disabled',true);
        scope.clickAndDisable().finally(function() {
          iElement.prop('disabled',false);
        })
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This can be used on a button as follows:

```
<button click-and-disable="functionThatReturnsPromise()">Click me</button>
```